# PHP, return a set number of characters after finding the string in a string(variable)

Tags: php, string, piping

I am trying to fetch details from an email pipe. the pipe returns the $message variable to me which contains allot of data. I want to be able to search the string for a specific value and return the next 'x' amount of characters.

as an example, my variable `$message` contains the below string:

```
Arrived at Inbound Receiving occurred

on M03-Actros 33.50 (1231) (MX1) (LT) 1022 on 2012-12-03

16:36:04



               * Driver ID: person, RT (1231) 

                * Vehicle Desc: M03-Actros 33.50 (1234) (MX1) (LT) 

                * Vehicle ID: 1022 

                * Time Stamp: 2012-12-03 16:36:04 

                * Latitude: S31 11.870' 

                * Longitude: E031 44.555' 

                * Speed: 7 km/h 

                * Heading: 356 deg (N) 

                * Event ID: -48 

                * Event Desc: .Arrived at Inbound Receiving 

                * Event Value: -56

                * Event Value Type: 0
```

I then want to filter out the Event Desc. so search `$message` for string 'Event Desc:' and then return the remaining data on that line. so from the above example I want to set the value of variable '$event' to '.Arrived at Inbound Receiving'

I know I have to use

```
if (strstr($subject, 'Event Desc: ')) {

}
```

but am not sure how to then return the remaining data on row given that the data can vary in length.

Any help appreciated as always, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
$event = null;
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $message);
foreach($lines as $line) {
  // skip empty lines
  if(strlen($line) == 0) {
    continue;
  }
  $tokens = explode(':', $line);
  // tokens[0] contains the key , e.g. Event Value
  // tokens[1]~[N] contains the value (where N is the number of pieces), e.g. -56
  // stitch token 1 ~ N
  $key = $tokens[0]; 
  unset($tokens[0]);
  $val = implode(':', $tokens);
  // do your extra logic here, e.g. set $event variable to value
  if(strpos($key, 'Event Desc') > -1) {
    $event = $val;
  }
}
```

Limitation: your data cannot contain `:`

Comment: This is not answering the question.

Comment: Thanks Shivan for prompt reply, appreciated. Can you explain this a little to help me understand? How would I then set the variable `$event` to the value of the line remainder after : 'event descr'? Thanks again.

Comment: and my data will definitely contain `:`. sample data as per question. thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Shivan, appreciate this. Works great. one questions though, it returns: 'Arrived at Inbound Receiving =' any idea why the = is displayed? Thanks again.

Comment: double check your original `$message`. The code I suggest did not generate `=`